# BIP9: What happens if I make a segwit transaction after lock in but before activation?

Tags: segregated-witness, bip9-version-bits, soft-fork

Will it be treated a anyone-can-spend or do the nodes enforce the new rules?

Along the same lines, what exactly happens when we say a soft fork is activated?

- Are the enforced at the time SF becomes activated?
- Or they are always enforced from the moment you download the client, but we consider it safe to use after activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new rules are come into effect only when the softfork activates.

I am not completely sure, but I think in the case of segwit transactions these would be treated as non-standard nodes and thus not accept it in their mempool. If a miner does have it in their mempool, they will not mine it into a block.

Hopefully, everyone that receives it would immediately drop it, but I think that third parties could pick the input up with an `ANYBODY_CAN_SPEND` transaction. They'd need to deposit the transaction directly to a miner that mines this type of non-standard transactions though for it to be mined.